# find an object which has at least 1 parameter(out of three)that matches with corresponding parameter of each object from array

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

I'm creating a matching puzzle game, and I'm stuck in creating logic for this function.

`Node` is a class that has 3 parameters:

```
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
}
```

then if I have 2 node objects, say `n1` and `n2` and

```
(n1 == n2) if (n1.a == n2.a || n1.b == n2.b || n1.c == n2.c)
```

so if:

```
n1.a=6, n1.b=4, n1.c=3
```

and:

```
n2.a=4, n2.b=4, n2.c=5.
```

here `( n1 == n2 )` or `n1` connects with `n2` because `( n1.b == n2.b )`.

The problem: I need to write logic for the function that accepts an array of `node` objects, and it should return a `node` object that can connect with all the `node`s in the array. If a connecting node is impossible, it should return a null value. So the node returned should have at least 1 parameter in common with every object of the array.

I'm using ActionScript 3 but just need the logic part in either AS3 or pseudo-code.

Comment: What programming language ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I'm using as3 but i just need logic in either pseudo code or as3.

Comment: OK - fixed your tags for you.

Comment: k cool, do u have any idea of the logic I can use?

Comment: Not off-hand - it looks like quite an interesting problem though.

Comment: yes i first taught it was easy, but the solution depends on every object in the array.not very easy

Comment: if the array has just 3 objects, the definite solution is just creating a node by picking 1 param from each object.that way it can connect with all 3

Comment: You can think of it as a 3D problem - each node is a point in 3D space and your constraint is that all points must lie on one of 3 orthogonal planes.

Comment: yes but how to find a point that has a same distance from origin that every point has in at least one of its plane?doesn't this complicate the problem?

Comment: I don't know whether the 3D view is a good way to think about it - maybe sets work better - I think it's probably going to be iterative/backtracking though. If the number of nodes is not large then maybe you could just "brute force" it ?

Comment: no of nodes is not that large <100 but i'm using this function in a level generator so ill be calling it every time a number of times i add an basic element, so i would prefer not to brute force it but if i cant find a solution, then brute force it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a set of possible points that satisfy this condition, and filter it out at each new point added to the list. First you will have to spawn many "any-any" points, these must be differentiated from normal. You start the algorithm with one "any,any,any" point, then whenever a point (a,b,c) is added, you check the list of existing points, and drop any that are not compliant with "a,b,c", and a point with "any" is now axis-locked to either of the axes, meaning the first step makes "a,any,any","any,b,any","any,any,c" set of points in the list. This continues until either all the list is processed, or there are no points left in the list.

```
function allconnected(nodes:Vector.<Node>):Node {
    var list:Array=[];
    list.push({a:null,b:null,c:null}); // "any,any,any" initial object
    for (var i:int=nodes.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var node:Node=nodes[i]; // current node
        if (list.length==0) return null; // no nodes match
        for (var j:int=list.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
            var o:Object=list.splice(j,1)[0]; // get the element out of the array
            var pushed:Boolean=false;
            if (o.a!==null) if (!pushed && (o.a==node.a)) {
                list.push(o);
                pushed=true;
            }
            if (o.b!==null) if (!pushed && (o.b==node.b)) {
                list.push(o);
                pushed=true;
            }
            if (o.c!==null) if (!pushed && (o.c==node.c)) {
                list.push(o);
                pushed=true;
            }
            // if this point connects by either side, and the side is defined, push it back
            if (o.a===null) list.push({a:node.a,b:o.b,c:o.c});
            if (o.b===null) list.push({a:o.a,b:node.b,c:o.c});
            if (o.c===null) list.push({a:o.a,b:o.b,c:node.c});
            // and if any side is "any", push an axis-aligned object in the list
        } // this way new object that are aligned with current node 
        // are put into the array in an already processed segment, so we won't hit
        // an infinite loop
    }
    // okay if we are here, then there is something left in the array
    var result:Node=new Node();
    result.a=list[0].a; // 0 if null, this is pretty much OK
    result.b=list[0].b;
    result.c=list[0].c;
    return result;
}
```

This code has been written on-the-fly, and there might be errors inside, so don't blindly copy and paste, please.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple man ! I tested your code, take this example : n0 : 3,2,8; n1 : 2,7,8; n2 : 1,2,9; n3 : 0,6,0; n4 : 2,2,9; n5 : 8,7,9, here your code gave 3,7,9 but we can see that n3 (0,6,0) is not connected to 3,7,9, Second example : n0 : 8,9,4; n1 : 9,4,4; n2 : 0,3,2; n3 : 1,8,6; n4 : 5,0,9; n5 : 0,3,0, the code gave 8, 4, 6 which is not connected to n2, n4 and n5, all object used in these example are generated randomly. I tried to write something because I like this type of problems but yet now I didn't get a code that work in all cases.

Comment: Got it, I've told ya, there might be bugs. `if (!o.a)` returns true if `o.a==0`. Changed null comparisons to strict form `===` and `!==`, please check again.